# What function is called for cell with unchanged value?

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

What function is called when `saveCell` is called on unchanged values? If the previous value of cell is `100` and `saveCell` is called on the unchanged value which is `100`, neither `beforeSaveCell` nor `beforeSubmitCell` gets called. How could I handle this case?

I am using `jqGrid 4.6.0`

Comment: Could you describe the scenario more detailed? Do you use cell editing mode? Is some cell is in editing mode? Do you call explicitly the `saveCell` method in your code?

Comment: @Oleg Yes, I am using cell editing mode. I explicitly call `saveCell`

Comment: @Oleg I am using inline-editing for some cells and call `save-cell` to save a value.

Comment: **Sorry, but which editing mode you use: cell editing or inline editing?** It's very important. To use cell editing one have to add the option `cellEdit: true`. One can specify *additionally* the callbacks like `beforeEditCell`,  `beforeSaveCell`, `beforeSubmitCell` and so on. It's important to understand the the callbacks will be called **only during cell editing**. The callbacks will be not called if you use other editing modes (inline or form editing). If *the row* (not the cell) is in editing mode then one can call `saveCell` explicitly. One have to use `saveRow` in case of inline editing.

Comment: @Oleg I have used `editable:true` and `'cellEdit': true,` for a cell but the none of the callback gets called,if `saveCell` is called on the unchanged value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cell editing works in the following way: jqGrid saves the content of editable rows/cells inside of internal parameter of jqGrid `savedRow`, which type is array. The method `saveCell` (or `savedRow` in cae of usage inline editing) compare the current value from the editable cell with the previous saved content (from `savedRow`). If no changes done during editing then `restoreCell` will be called. The callbacks `beforeSaveCell` and `beforeSubmitCell` will be called only if the Ajax call will be send to the server (`cellsubmit: "remote"`) or if the changes needed be saved locally (`cellsubmit: "clientArray"`). After the successful saving of the data on the server or locally the callback `afterSaveCell` will be called.

You wrote that you calls `saveCell` *explicitly* in your code. Thus you can just examine whether the cell is changed or not before calling `saveCell`. What you need to do is including the tests like the code below do:

```
// below code uses $grid, which is jQuery wrapper to jqGrid (like $grid = $("#grid"))
// it uses additionally iRow and iCol variables which you use as parameters
// of the call of saveCell

var $t = $grid[0], // $t is the DOM of the grid
    p = $grid.jqGrid("getGridParam"), // get reference to all jqGrid parameters
    getTdByColumnIndex = function (tr, iCol) {
        // the function getTdByColumnIndex return jQuery wrapper
        // to one or two <td> elements. If frozen column is used
        // and the column iCol is frozen then the function
        // returns the wrapper to two <td> elements: one from
        // frozen div and another from original grid
        var $t = this, frozenRows = $t.grid.fbRows;
        return $((frozenRows != null && frozenRows[0].cells.length > iCol ? 
                  frozenRows[tr.rowIndex] :
                  tr).cells[iCol]);
    },
    tr = $t.rows[iRow], rowid = tr.id, $tr = $(tr), cm = p.colModel[iCol],
    savedRow = p.savedRow,
    fr = savedRow.length >= 1 ? 0 : null,
    nm = cm.name, v, cc = getTdByColumnIndex.call($t, tr, iCol);

v = $.jgrid.getEditedValue.call($t, cc, cm, !cm.formatter);
if (v !== savedRow[fr].v) {
    // the cell is changed you can call saveCell
    // and you will be sure that the changes will be saved
} else {
    // the cell is not changed
    // you can call
    // $grid.jqGrid("restoreCell", iRow, iCol);
    // directly
}
```

I get the above code from the existing code of free jqGrid. Additionally, before all, one should test whether the column `iCol` is editable or not. If you knows exactly which editable type have the column and whether you use frozen columns or not then you can simplify your code

Comment: Also, cell automatically gets saved when clicked on another cell in the grid. Can this be disabled?

Comment: @SuhailGupta: No you can't change the behavior, because it's the base behavior of cell editing. Inline editing don't have any binding on the `click` event and you can implement any your custom behavior.

Comment: My grid keeps on refreshing, but the timer is cleared when any editable cell is clicked. After the user has filled in values and cell saved grid should restart to refresh. I could handle the restarting of refresh in `beforeSubmitCell` but where could I handle the restart where cell value doesn't change?

Comment: @SuhailGupta: Sorry, but I still don't full understand what you implemented exactly. When the refresh is started? Do you have some kind of auto-refreshing in specific time intervals or you trigger `reloadGrid` in some conditions? I don't understand why you want that `beforeSubmitCell` be called if nothing is changed in the grid. Please formulate more clear the question to me. I can't answer on the question "where could I handle the restart where cell value doesn't change?" if I don't know what you implemented exactly.

Comment: Grid keeps on refreshing at regular intervals by calling `reloadGrid`. There isn't a condition attached to `reloadGrid` as shown here http://pastebin.com/zMbXEXdA When any editable cell is clicked timer gets cleared by calling `beforeEditCell`  to restart it when any of the cell is not in editing mode.

Comment: So, what function should be called to restart the refresh whether the cell value changed or not.(or restart the refresh when any of the cell is not in editing mode)

Comment: @SuhailGupta: I still don't see when you execute `setGridRefreshTimer`, what you do in `beforeEditCell` and what is your goal. Do you want to ttrigger `reloadGrid` in some intervals of time, but you have some conditions to skip reloading? I would just include the testing of the conditions **inside of `setInterval`, directly before executing `grid.trigger("reloadGrid");`**. You can just test whether `p.savedRow.length > 0` then the grid is inside of cell or inline editing.

Comment: @SuhailGupta: Free jqGrid set `p.jqXhr` additionally during processing of pending Ajax request. You can test for `p.jqXhr != null` additionally. You can use `abortAjaxRequest` method to abort the pending Ajax request or to skip triggering of new `reloadGrid` in the case.

Comment: Is there a way I could exit `cell editing`? I tried `restoreRow`, but I think it will not work for `cell editing`

Comment: @SuhailGupta: You can exist cell editing either by `restoreCell` or by `saveCell`. Moreover you can *prevent* cell editing (don't start the editing of some cells) either by adding `not-editable-cell` class to the cell of by usage `editable` property defined as callback function instead of boolean (see [the wiki article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/editable-property-of-colModel-as-function)). The last feature exist only in free jqGrid.

Comment: How could I stop sorting by `groupField`? I added `groupDataSorted : false` to no effect.

Comment: @SuhailGupta: I'm not sure what you mean and want you do exactly, but to be able to group by some field one have to sort the data by the field to be able to display all items from the same group together. Thus if you need to use grouping by some field you *have to* sort by the filed.

Comment: I need to sort the data only by unique `ID` in the `DB`, The grouping field is  `Name`. Since the data is also sorted by `Name` I do not get the order I intend to see! The query that is run finally `Select ifnull(ji.JobID,' ') as JobID, ifnull(ji.FileName,' ') as FileName, 
 ifnull(ji.EndIndex,' ') as EndIndex, ifnull(ji.SplitIndex,' ') as SplitIndex, ifnull(ji.Duration,'') as Duration, 
 ifnull(ji.FileSize,'') as FileSize, ci.Name from job_info as ji right join 
 content_info as ci on ji.ContainerID = ci.ID order by ci.Name asc, ci.ID desc LIMIT 0 , 20`

Comment: However I would only want to `order by ci.ID desc`. Is there any way I could do this?

Comment: @SuhailGupta: Do you want that all items with the same `Name` will be display together? For example you have `Name: 'Suhail', ID:5`, `Name: 'Oleg', ID:10`, `Name: 'Suhail', ID:15`, `Name: 'Oleg', ID:20`. To be able to display the data grouped by `name` and sorted desc by `ID` one have to sort the data by `Name asc, ID desc` Then the data will be displayed in the order `Name: 'Oleg', ID:20`, `Name: 'Oleg', ID:10`, `Name: 'Suhail', ID:15`, `Name: 'Suhail', ID:5`. jqGrid will display `Oleg` and `Suhail` as groups and to display desc sorted data inside every group. Thus all looks correctly.

Comment: Could the sort order be changed? I intend to sort by `ID` first and then by `Name` _(Name is the groupheader field)_

Comment: @SuhailGupta: Sorry, but I can't follow you, I posted you before the example with the data: `Name: 'Suhail', ID:5, Name: 'Oleg', ID:10, Name: 'Suhail', ID:15, Name: 'Oleg', ID:20`. **How (in which order) you imagine to display the data? Displaying the data grouped by `Name` implys sorting by `name` as first.** You can look on the problem from another point of view. Which SQL statement you would find correct? The statement `SELECT ID FROM job_info GROUP BY Name ORDER BY ID DESC` means **first** sorting by `Name` to make grouping and then by `ID` to sort the data *inside of every group*.

Comment: Yes, `GROUP BY Name ORDER BY ID DESC` will give me the result!

Comment: Will I need to manipulate the value from  `$_GET['sidx']` or is there something inbuilt to obtain `groupheader` and `column sort` separately?

Comment: @SuhailGupta: But `GROUP BY Name ORDER BY ID DESC` means practically **the same** as `ORDER BY Name ASC, ID DESC` because the returned items are all with the same `name` (like `Oleg` and then `Suhail`) and then the data are sorted inside of the group only. To be exactly to display `ID` in the results, one have to use `GROUP BY Name, ID ORDER BY Name, ID DESC`. SQL don't allows to use in SELECT other fields as the fields from `GROUP BY` (if one don't use aggregation functions like `COUNT` and so on)

Comment: Can I disable `escape` and `enter` key in **cell editing** mode?

Comment: @SuhailGupta: Yes, you can unbind `keydown` inside of `afterEditCell` callback or `jqGridAfterEditCell` event. Please post more questions instead of asking new questions in the comment. The same problems could have other people. Only separate questions can be indexed and found. The goal of stackoverflow is sharing common problem and solutions with other. You can help other people only by posting **separate questions**.